# Default arrowhead primitives

Tags: graphics, default

Are there source files with `Line`s etc. that produce (boundary of) the default arrowhead

[image: arrow]

I'm imagining something like

```
FlipView[{Graphics[
 FilledCurve@{Line@{{19,19},{0,8}},BezierCurve@{{0,8},{7,7},{8,0}}},
  ImageSize->Large], 
   Show[Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9lzt.png", ImageSize -> Large]}]
```

although my approximation with a `BezierCurve` doesn't match.

Comment: does `Arrowheads /. CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics"}]` give what you need?

Comment: I'm not interested in the default size, I'm interested in the outline that forms the arrowhead glyph

Comment: Do you want a definition of the boundary for the arrowhead? You should edit your question to make this explicitly clear. As it is, it is not clear what you want.

Comment: This is a really interesting question & I hope someone can help to find a good answer. I feel like there should be a way to use the `Region` functions to solve this.